# Simplify $\int_0^1 \int_0^x F(x,y)\, dy \,dx$ to 1-dim. integral

Tags: integration

$F(x,y)$ can be written as $f(y)$, where $f$ is integrable.

I mean I can just define me a function $\displaystyle g(x) = \int_0^x f(y)$ that only depends on $x$ and then integrate it over $[0,1]$, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: You could try reversing the order of integration. Your integral is equivalent to $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_y^1 F(x,y) \, dx \, dy$. It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Do you know what $F(x,y)$ is?

Comment: No. I gave you all information I have about $F(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah. Well, your idea is basically a good one, I think, except that I don't think you can drop the $x$ in $F(x,y)$. Let $g(x)=\int_0^x F(x,y) \, dy$.